# Can not load "coffee", it is not registered! Karma error message

Tags: coffeescript, karma-runner

I am trying to use Karma with Coffeescript. The following preprocessor line is there in karma config file:

> ```
> preprocessors: {
>   '**/*.coffee': 'coffee'
> }
> ```

But I am getting the error -

> Can not load "coffee", it is not registered!
>
> Perhaps you are missing some plugin?

karma-coffee-preprocessor is available as devDependencies in package.json. Has anyone faced this issue? Thanks.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor), try changing `: 'coffee'` to `: ['coffee']`

Comment: @LcLk Tried that too. No difference in the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. It is because of not installing karma-cli. I though installing karma globally is enough. But after installing karma-cli everything is fine.